# Better Performance to Exit Function at Top of Code or After It?

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine

My title probably doesn't make sense. But basically I have always done a function like this.

```
void Start() {
   if (someBoolean) {
      /*
       *
       Do My Code
       which could be a lot
       *
      */
   }
}
```

But I recently saw this something like this in the [Unity Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-textureCoord.html).

```
void Start() {
    if (!someBoolean) return;

       /*
        *
        Do My Code
        which could be a lot
        *
        */
    }
```

With if statements I am aware that the code is skipped, but does doing this make a difference in perspective of performance?

Of course, I do realize it can also be preference to do it this way, which I do actually like. It looks a lot more sequential to me.

My question is does doing this effect the performance at all?

=============================

I am going to mark the answer below as correct, as that seems to be correct. I am just going to include the link that was put in the comments as this question has been answered:
[Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18454/should-i-return-from-a-function-early-or-use-an-if-statement)

Comment: the compiler is incredibly smart. also your 2nd example is not valid c#

Comment: So it is smart..does that it does not make any difference?

Comment: it can reorder your code as it best sees fit, it may do this under the covers for you.

Comment: Also I changed the examples. I just quickly put it in there as an example code.

Comment: An early exit shouldn't affect performance, but can give a quick improvement to readability. See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/18454/should-i-return-from-a-function-early-or-use-an-if-statement

Comment: you will have to look at the generated msil to see if there's any benefit.

Comment: @Serlite that is what I was looking for. I tried to search before posting, but wasn't sure exactly what to google. Thank you!

Comment: You should remove all references to asking for "better to" in your question and instead focus on the performance question. As it stands now it risks being closed as based on opinions.

Comment: The early exit makes things (read: exit conditions) clear. The late one hides the fact that it even is one until all the code has been read and understood.

Comment: Yeah, I really do like the second way best and I am going to start using it. It just makes more sense to me and seems to for others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no performance difference between these two examples. The compiler will most likely generate the same binary code for both examples.

I personally prefer the second example to reduce indentation depth, but there are also many people who prefer the first because it supposedly makes code easier to read by having only a single exit point.